# how to find common name objects in json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

i'm looking for a json logic for 2 hours and i haven't found any solution.
My json data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d020135436357a4732e",
    "balance": "1,171.56",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Key"
    },
    "company": "Orbaxter",
    "email": "colonkey@orbaxter.com",
    "phone": "+1 (938) 402-3422",
    "address": "706 Tennis Court, Kimmell, Indiana, 4057",
    "registered": "2014-12-24T10:31:42 -00:00",
    "latitude": 22.250647,
    "longitude": -67.325278
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d027f167186f52e2e6c",
    "balance": "1,383.36",
    "age": 23,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Byrd",
      "last": "Walls"
    },
    "company": "Bizmatic",
    "email": "byrdwalls@bizmatic.com",
    "phone": "+1 (817) 569-3406",
    "address": "187 Lewis Avenue, Lutsen, Oregon, 7387",
    "registered": "2017-06-19T09:24:42 -01:00",
    "latitude": -60.642235,
    "longitude": -62.947158
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d023f1f434dcb1ea87d",
    "balance": "2,338.81",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sondra",
      "last": "Booker"
    },
    "company": "Aquazure",
    "email": "sondrabooker@aquazure.com",
    "phone": "+1 (861) 495-3729",
    "address": "633 Billings Place, Jacumba, Louisiana, 1488",
    "registered": "2017-12-11T08:53:27 -00:00",
    "latitude": 18.681413,
    "longitude": 93.058578
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02826a978c51641cfb",
    "balance": "2,959.74",
    "age": 40,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Tammi",
      "last": "Salazar"
    },
    "company": "Terascape",
    "email": "tammisalazar@terascape.com",
    "phone": "+1 (906) 405-2566",
    "address": "470 Elliott Walk, Gibbsville, New Mexico, 7298",
    "registered": "2014-08-06T09:06:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": -75.890626,
    "longitude": 19.674008
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02dd1046807a0e3636",
    "balance": "1,960.08",
    "age": 42,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Maryellen",
      "last": "Merritt"
    },
    "company": "Digial",
    "email": "maryellenmerritt@digial.com",
    "phone": "+1 (802) 566-3481",
    "address": "189 Jerome Street, Hoehne, Palau, 8982",
    "registered": "2017-06-18T10:16:48 -01:00",
    "latitude": -16.254906,
    "longitude": 112.500547
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02081e34940395696e",
    "balance": "3,324.41",
    "age": 49,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Liz",
      "last": "Harrell"
    },
    "company": "Codact",
    "email": "lizharrell@codact.com",
    "phone": "+1 (957) 530-3553",
    "address": "575 Waldane Court, Sussex, New Hampshire, 9982",
    "registered": "2017-01-13T10:09:11 -00:00",
    "latitude": -86.073799,
    "longitude": -48.573135
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d024a9ea40d4c2ca212",
    "balance": "2,364.05",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Sharp"
    },
    "company": "Hopeli",
    "email": "luzsharp@hopeli.com",
    "phone": "+1 (843) 536-2721",
    "address": "225 Huron Street, Richford, Iowa, 7066",
    "registered": "2016-09-16T08:01:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": 26.918633,
    "longitude": -24.304009
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02b08119b44fd33946",
    "balance": "2,040.30",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Celina",
      "last": "Hammond"
    },
    "company": "Digigene",
    "email": "celinahammond@digigene.com",
    "phone": "+1 (964) 445-3260",
    "address": "433 Sumner Place, Wedgewood, Arizona, 6033",
    "registered": "2017-11-21T05:27:38 -00:00",
    "latitude": -21.626178,
    "longitude": -65.326728
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d021508ef1683fca66d",
    "balance": "1,930.37",
    "age": 50,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Alexis",
      "last": "Chan"
    },
    "company": "Concility",
    "email": "alexischan@concility.com",
    "phone": "+1 (973) 527-2328",
    "address": "444 Anchorage Place, Dundee, Alaska, 2502",
    "registered": "2014-02-14T12:21:44 -00:00",
    "latitude": -2.539619,
    "longitude": 95.660992
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02fc383d361e1de77c",
    "balance": "1,887.65",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Jessica",
      "last": "Park"
    },
    "company": "Kangle",
    "email": "jessicapark@kangle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (842) 474-2417",
    "address": "183 Mersereau Court, Hollymead, Colorado, 8797",
    "registered": "2014-01-21T09:50:45 -00:00",
    "latitude": -55.563378,
    "longitude": -17.215224
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02aec3b3758323f307",
    "balance": "2,271.43",
    "age": 44,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sutton",
      "last": "Nixon"
    },
    "company": "Frolix",
    "email": "suttonnixon@frolix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (927) 475-2590",
    "address": "483 Junius Street, Corinne, Kentucky, 6142",
    "registered": "2016-02-16T07:51:36 -00:00",
    "latitude": -69.55902,
    "longitude": 49.509631
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d0210036f470ba9906f",
    "balance": "2,268.91",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Reba",
      "last": "Osborne"
    },
    "company": "Ovation",
    "email": "rebaosborne@ovation.com",
    "phone": "+1 (905) 502-3225",
    "address": "586 Beaver Street, Edenburg, Wyoming, 8712",
    "registered": "2016-03-02T06:08:48 -00:00",
    "latitude": 57.737613,
    "longitude": -49.301794
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02f2a230afbc80f82e",
    "balance": "3,633.00",
    "age": 54,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Hardy",
      "last": "Cotton"
    },
    "company": "Futurize",
    "email": "hardycotton@futurize.com",
    "phone": "+1 (969) 427-2003",
    "address": "923 Miami Court, Knowlton, Ohio, 4026",
    "registered": "2016-02-22T07:35:28 -00:00",
    "latitude": 84.25911,
    "longitude": 136.825862
  }
]
```

This is really a large file, so i pasted some of it. How can I find all the people with common surnames (that means common first name's of the json data)?

I'm using ajax request in javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript find json value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253753/javascript-find-json-value)

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample data you have given? Also, is it about surnames or first names? You mention both...

Comment: What do you mean by 'common' surnames? Just names or names that statisfy some criterias?

Comment: Hi @trincot, the json file has name object in it and there are multiple names which repeats again and i need to find those common names according to their surname, that means first name.

Comment: Ow, well in my understanding surname is last name, not first name, but OK, I now see you mean first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `reduce()` and group the ids by name,

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d020135436357a4732e",
    "balance": "1,171.56",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Key"
    },
    "company": "Orbaxter",
    "email": "colonkey@orbaxter.com",
    "phone": "+1 (938) 402-3422",
    "address": "706 Tennis Court, Kimmell, Indiana, 4057",
    "registered": "2014-12-24T10:31:42 -00:00",
    "latitude": 22.250647,
    "longitude": -67.325278
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d027f167186f52e2e6c",
    "balance": "1,383.36",
    "age": 23,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Walls"
    },
    "company": "Bizmatic",
    "email": "byrdwalls@bizmatic.com",
    "phone": "+1 (817) 569-3406",
    "address": "187 Lewis Avenue, Lutsen, Oregon, 7387",
    "registered": "2017-06-19T09:24:42 -01:00",
    "latitude": -60.642235,
    "longitude": -62.947158
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d023f1f434dcb1ea87d",
    "balance": "2,338.81",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Booker"
    },
    "company": "Aquazure",
    "email": "sondrabooker@aquazure.com",
    "phone": "+1 (861) 495-3729",
    "address": "633 Billings Place, Jacumba, Louisiana, 1488",
    "registered": "2017-12-11T08:53:27 -00:00",
    "latitude": 18.681413,
    "longitude": 93.058578
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02826a978c51641cfb",
    "balance": "2,959.74",
    "age": 40,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Tammi",
      "last": "Salazar"
    },
    "company": "Terascape",
    "email": "tammisalazar@terascape.com",
    "phone": "+1 (906) 405-2566",
    "address": "470 Elliott Walk, Gibbsville, New Mexico, 7298",
    "registered": "2014-08-06T09:06:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": -75.890626,
    "longitude": 19.674008
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02dd1046807a0e3636",
    "balance": "1,960.08",
    "age": 42,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Tammi",
      "last": "Merritt"
    },
    "company": "Digial",
    "email": "maryellenmerritt@digial.com",
    "phone": "+1 (802) 566-3481",
    "address": "189 Jerome Street, Hoehne, Palau, 8982",
    "registered": "2017-06-18T10:16:48 -01:00",
    "latitude": -16.254906,
    "longitude": 112.500547
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02081e34940395696e",
    "balance": "3,324.41",
    "age": 49,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Liz",
      "last": "Harrell"
    },
    "company": "Codact",
    "email": "lizharrell@codact.com",
    "phone": "+1 (957) 530-3553",
    "address": "575 Waldane Court, Sussex, New Hampshire, 9982",
    "registered": "2017-01-13T10:09:11 -00:00",
    "latitude": -86.073799,
    "longitude": -48.573135
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d024a9ea40d4c2ca212",
    "balance": "2,364.05",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Sharp"
    },
    "company": "Hopeli",
    "email": "luzsharp@hopeli.com",
    "phone": "+1 (843) 536-2721",
    "address": "225 Huron Street, Richford, Iowa, 7066",
    "registered": "2016-09-16T08:01:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": 26.918633,
    "longitude": -24.304009
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02b08119b44fd33946",
    "balance": "2,040.30",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Hammond"
    },
    "company": "Digigene",
    "email": "celinahammond@digigene.com",
    "phone": "+1 (964) 445-3260",
    "address": "433 Sumner Place, Wedgewood, Arizona, 6033",
    "registered": "2017-11-21T05:27:38 -00:00",
    "latitude": -21.626178,
    "longitude": -65.326728
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d021508ef1683fca66d",
    "balance": "1,930.37",
    "age": 50,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Chan"
    },
    "company": "Concility",
    "email": "alexischan@concility.com",
    "phone": "+1 (973) 527-2328",
    "address": "444 Anchorage Place, Dundee, Alaska, 2502",
    "registered": "2014-02-14T12:21:44 -00:00",
    "latitude": -2.539619,
    "longitude": 95.660992
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02fc383d361e1de77c",
    "balance": "1,887.65",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Park"
    },
    "company": "Kangle",
    "email": "jessicapark@kangle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (842) 474-2417",
    "address": "183 Mersereau Court, Hollymead, Colorado, 8797",
    "registered": "2014-01-21T09:50:45 -00:00",
    "latitude": -55.563378,
    "longitude": -17.215224
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02aec3b3758323f307",
    "balance": "2,271.43",
    "age": 44,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sutton",
      "last": "Nixon"
    },
    "company": "Frolix",
    "email": "suttonnixon@frolix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (927) 475-2590",
    "address": "483 Junius Street, Corinne, Kentucky, 6142",
    "registered": "2016-02-16T07:51:36 -00:00",
    "latitude": -69.55902,
    "longitude": 49.509631
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d0210036f470ba9906f",
    "balance": "2,268.91",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sutton",
      "last": "Osborne"
    },
    "company": "Ovation",
    "email": "rebaosborne@ovation.com",
    "phone": "+1 (905) 502-3225",
    "address": "586 Beaver Street, Edenburg, Wyoming, 8712",
    "registered": "2016-03-02T06:08:48 -00:00",
    "latitude": 57.737613,
    "longitude": -49.301794
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02f2a230afbc80f82e",
    "balance": "3,633.00",
    "age": 54,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Hardy",
      "last": "Cotton"
    },
    "company": "Futurize",
    "email": "hardycotton@futurize.com",
    "phone": "+1 (969) 427-2003",
    "address": "923 Miami Court, Knowlton, Ohio, 4026",
    "registered": "2016-02-22T07:35:28 -00:00",
    "latitude": 84.25911,
    "longitude": 136.825862
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02519a87f76fc8a0e6",
    "balance": "1,902.75",
    "age": 47,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Ashlee",
      "last": "Gregory"
    }
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((all, curr) => {
  (all[curr.name.first] = all[curr.name.first] || []).push(
  curr["_id"]
  );

  return all;
}, {});

const formattedResult = Object.entries(result).map(([name, ids]) => ({
  name,
  ids,
  repeated : ids.length,  
}));

console.log(formattedResult);

// for top 5 repeated names : 
const topFive = formattedResult.sort((a,b) => b.repeated - a.repeated).slice(0, 5);
```

the resulting `Object` will have the `name` as keys and the `ids` of the corresponding values with the same name, ( i modified your input for the second name for the sake of the demo )

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! But i'm looking for common names(first name) which are repeated more in increasing order. also wants to find individual lengths of each common names.

Comment: i updated the answer so the result would be an array of objects containing the `name`, the ids of users having that name and `repeated` times, they are in the same order of the original list,

Comment: It works!! I tried this with my large json file and there are around 20,000 names in it and i also tried top 5 repeated common names but im not able to get it cause each name repeats 5 or 6 times equally .

Comment: cool, but i don't understand what is it you're not able to get

Comment: you are finding it by the id's  repeated : ids.length + " times"  but i want them by the first name. in my original json file 'Colon' name repeated 50 times but in your code its only calculating 5 times.

Comment: no, i'm finding them by the repeated `name.first` then i put the corresponding `id` in the array and display its length, did you check the spelling and wheather it's capital letters ?

Comment: yeah! yeah! you're absolutely right. That's really helpful and now what im trying to do is showing the top 5 most common with their totals.

Comment: do you know how to find nearest person living to eiffel tower using lat and lang in this json?

Comment: this should help you do that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819224/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-json-data

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gather the names, you can map on your data and extract the `name` and then `first`:

```
const names = data.map(item => item.name ? item.name.first : '');
```

If you want to group all people with the same name, then use `reduce`. For example to gather the `_id`'s:

```
const sameNames = data.reduce((accum, { name: { first }, _id }) => {
  accum[first] = [...(accum[first] || []), _id];
  return accum;
}, {});
```

Here is an example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d020135436357a4732e",
    "balance": "1,171.56",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Key"
    },
    "company": "Orbaxter",
    "email": "colonkey@orbaxter.com",
    "phone": "+1 (938) 402-3422",
    "address": "706 Tennis Court, Kimmell, Indiana, 4057",
    "registered": "2014-12-24T10:31:42 -00:00",
    "latitude": 22.250647,
    "longitude": -67.325278
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d027f167186f52e2e6c",
    "balance": "1,383.36",
    "age": 23,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Byrd",
      "last": "Walls"
    },
    "company": "Bizmatic",
    "email": "byrdwalls@bizmatic.com",
    "phone": "+1 (817) 569-3406",
    "address": "187 Lewis Avenue, Lutsen, Oregon, 7387",
    "registered": "2017-06-19T09:24:42 -01:00",
    "latitude": -60.642235,
    "longitude": -62.947158
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d023f1f434dcb1ea87d",
    "balance": "2,338.81",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Booker"
    },
    "company": "Aquazure",
    "email": "sondrabooker@aquazure.com",
    "phone": "+1 (861) 495-3729",
    "address": "633 Billings Place, Jacumba, Louisiana, 1488",
    "registered": "2017-12-11T08:53:27 -00:00",
    "latitude": 18.681413,
    "longitude": 93.058578
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02826a978c51641cfb",
    "balance": "2,959.74",
    "age": 40,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Tammi",
      "last": "Salazar"
    },
    "company": "Terascape",
    "email": "tammisalazar@terascape.com",
    "phone": "+1 (906) 405-2566",
    "address": "470 Elliott Walk, Gibbsville, New Mexico, 7298",
    "registered": "2014-08-06T09:06:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": -75.890626,
    "longitude": 19.674008
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02dd1046807a0e3636",
    "balance": "1,960.08",
    "age": 42,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Maryellen",
      "last": "Merritt"
    },
    "company": "Digial",
    "email": "maryellenmerritt@digial.com",
    "phone": "+1 (802) 566-3481",
    "address": "189 Jerome Street, Hoehne, Palau, 8982",
    "registered": "2017-06-18T10:16:48 -01:00",
    "latitude": -16.254906,
    "longitude": 112.500547
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02081e34940395696e",
    "balance": "3,324.41",
    "age": 49,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Liz",
      "last": "Harrell"
    },
    "company": "Codact",
    "email": "lizharrell@codact.com",
    "phone": "+1 (957) 530-3553",
    "address": "575 Waldane Court, Sussex, New Hampshire, 9982",
    "registered": "2017-01-13T10:09:11 -00:00",
    "latitude": -86.073799,
    "longitude": -48.573135
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d024a9ea40d4c2ca212",
    "balance": "2,364.05",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Sharp"
    },
    "company": "Hopeli",
    "email": "luzsharp@hopeli.com",
    "phone": "+1 (843) 536-2721",
    "address": "225 Huron Street, Richford, Iowa, 7066",
    "registered": "2016-09-16T08:01:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": 26.918633,
    "longitude": -24.304009
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02b08119b44fd33946",
    "balance": "2,040.30",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Liz",
      "last": "Hammond"
    },
    "company": "Digigene",
    "email": "celinahammond@digigene.com",
    "phone": "+1 (964) 445-3260",
    "address": "433 Sumner Place, Wedgewood, Arizona, 6033",
    "registered": "2017-11-21T05:27:38 -00:00",
    "latitude": -21.626178,
    "longitude": -65.326728
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d021508ef1683fca66d",
    "balance": "1,930.37",
    "age": 50,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Alexis",
      "last": "Chan"
    },
    "company": "Concility",
    "email": "alexischan@concility.com",
    "phone": "+1 (973) 527-2328",
    "address": "444 Anchorage Place, Dundee, Alaska, 2502",
    "registered": "2014-02-14T12:21:44 -00:00",
    "latitude": -2.539619,
    "longitude": 95.660992
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02fc383d361e1de77c",
    "balance": "1,887.65",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Jessica",
      "last": "Park"
    },
    "company": "Kangle",
    "email": "jessicapark@kangle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (842) 474-2417",
    "address": "183 Mersereau Court, Hollymead, Colorado, 8797",
    "registered": "2014-01-21T09:50:45 -00:00",
    "latitude": -55.563378,
    "longitude": -17.215224
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02aec3b3758323f307",
    "balance": "2,271.43",
    "age": 44,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sutton",
      "last": "Nixon"
    },
    "company": "Frolix",
    "email": "suttonnixon@frolix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (927) 475-2590",
    "address": "483 Junius Street, Corinne, Kentucky, 6142",
    "registered": "2016-02-16T07:51:36 -00:00",
    "latitude": -69.55902,
    "longitude": 49.509631
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d0210036f470ba9906f",
    "balance": "2,268.91",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Reba",
      "last": "Osborne"
    },
    "company": "Ovation",
    "email": "rebaosborne@ovation.com",
    "phone": "+1 (905) 502-3225",
    "address": "586 Beaver Street, Edenburg, Wyoming, 8712",
    "registered": "2016-03-02T06:08:48 -00:00",
    "latitude": 57.737613,
    "longitude": -49.301794
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02f2a230afbc80f82e",
    "balance": "3,633.00",
    "age": 54,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sutton",
      "last": "Cotton"
    },
    "company": "Futurize",
    "email": "hardycotton@futurize.com",
    "phone": "+1 (969) 427-2003",
    "address": "923 Miami Court, Knowlton, Ohio, 4026",
    "registered": "2016-02-22T07:35:28 -00:00",
    "latitude": 84.25911,
    "longitude": 136.825862
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d02519a87f76fc8a0e6",
    "balance": "1,902.75",
    "age": 47,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Ashlee",
      "last": "Gregory"
    }
  }
];

const sameNames = data.reduce((accum, { name: { first }, _id }) => {
  accum[first] = [...(accum[first] || []), _id];
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(sameNames);
```

Comment: This does not group the users by first name though. It only return an array of first names

Comment: You are right, the OP updated its question, I will adjust my answer

Answer (score 0):

To group your users by *first name* you can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function. This will create an object which has *first names* as *keys* and *user groups* as *values*.

- If the *first name* is not in the final object, you add it as a key with a an array containing only that user as a value
- If it's already there, append it to the value

```js
const groupUsersByFirstName = arr => arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!(curr.name.first in acc)) {
     acc[curr.name.first] = [curr];
  } else {
     acc[curr.name.first].append(curr);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

const users = [{
    "_id": "5ae30d020135436357a4732e",
    "balance": "1,171.56",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Colon",
      "last": "Key"
    },
    "company": "Orbaxter",
    "email": "colonkey@orbaxter.com",
    "phone": "+1 (938) 402-3422",
    "address": "706 Tennis Court, Kimmell, Indiana, 4057",
    "registered": "2014-12-24T10:31:42 -00:00",
    "latitude": 22.250647,
    "longitude": -67.325278
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ae30d027f167186f52e2e6c",
    "balance": "1,383.36",
    "age": 23,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Byrd",
      "last": "Walls"
    },
    "company": "Bizmatic",
    "email": "byrdwalls@bizmatic.com",
    "phone": "+1 (817) 569-3406",
    "address": "187 Lewis Avenue, Lutsen, Oregon, 7387",
    "registered": "2017-06-19T09:24:42 -01:00",
    "latitude": -60.642235,
    "longitude": -62.947158
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d023f1f434dcb1ea87d",
    "balance": "2,338.81",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sondra",
      "last": "Booker"
    },
    "company": "Aquazure",
    "email": "sondrabooker@aquazure.com",
    "phone": "+1 (861) 495-3729",
    "address": "633 Billings Place, Jacumba, Louisiana, 1488",
    "registered": "2017-12-11T08:53:27 -00:00",
    "latitude": 18.681413,
    "longitude": 93.058578
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02826a978c51641cfb",
    "balance": "2,959.74",
    "age": 40,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Tammi",
      "last": "Salazar"
    },
    "company": "Terascape",
    "email": "tammisalazar@terascape.com",
    "phone": "+1 (906) 405-2566",
    "address": "470 Elliott Walk, Gibbsville, New Mexico, 7298",
    "registered": "2014-08-06T09:06:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": -75.890626,
    "longitude": 19.674008
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02dd1046807a0e3636",
    "balance": "1,960.08",
    "age": 42,
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "name": {
      "first": "Maryellen",
      "last": "Merritt"
    },
    "company": "Digial",
    "email": "maryellenmerritt@digial.com",
    "phone": "+1 (802) 566-3481",
    "address": "189 Jerome Street, Hoehne, Palau, 8982",
    "registered": "2017-06-18T10:16:48 -01:00",
    "latitude": -16.254906,
    "longitude": 112.500547
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02081e34940395696e",
    "balance": "3,324.41",
    "age": 49,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Liz",
      "last": "Harrell"
    },
    "company": "Codact",
    "email": "lizharrell@codact.com",
    "phone": "+1 (957) 530-3553",
    "address": "575 Waldane Court, Sussex, New Hampshire, 9982",
    "registered": "2017-01-13T10:09:11 -00:00",
    "latitude": -86.073799,
    "longitude": -48.573135
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d024a9ea40d4c2ca212",
    "balance": "2,364.05",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Luz",
      "last": "Sharp"
    },
    "company": "Hopeli",
    "email": "luzsharp@hopeli.com",
    "phone": "+1 (843) 536-2721",
    "address": "225 Huron Street, Richford, Iowa, 7066",
    "registered": "2016-09-16T08:01:17 -01:00",
    "latitude": 26.918633,
    "longitude": -24.304009
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02b08119b44fd33946",
    "balance": "2,040.30",
    "age": 21,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Celina",
      "last": "Hammond"
    },
    "company": "Digigene",
    "email": "celinahammond@digigene.com",
    "phone": "+1 (964) 445-3260",
    "address": "433 Sumner Place, Wedgewood, Arizona, 6033",
    "registered": "2017-11-21T05:27:38 -00:00",
    "latitude": -21.626178,
    "longitude": -65.326728
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d021508ef1683fca66d",
    "balance": "1,930.37",
    "age": 50,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Alexis",
      "last": "Chan"
    },
    "company": "Concility",
    "email": "alexischan@concility.com",
    "phone": "+1 (973) 527-2328",
    "address": "444 Anchorage Place, Dundee, Alaska, 2502",
    "registered": "2014-02-14T12:21:44 -00:00",
    "latitude": -2.539619,
    "longitude": 95.660992
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02fc383d361e1de77c",
    "balance": "1,887.65",
    "age": 35,
    "eyeColor": "grey",
    "name": {
      "first": "Jessica",
      "last": "Park"
    },
    "company": "Kangle",
    "email": "jessicapark@kangle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (842) 474-2417",
    "address": "183 Mersereau Court, Hollymead, Colorado, 8797",
    "registered": "2014-01-21T09:50:45 -00:00",
    "latitude": -55.563378,
    "longitude": -17.215224
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02aec3b3758323f307",
    "balance": "2,271.43",
    "age": 44,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": {
      "first": "Sutton",
      "last": "Nixon"
    },
    "company": "Frolix",
    "email": "suttonnixon@frolix.com",
    "phone": "+1 (927) 475-2590",
    "address": "483 Junius Street, Corinne, Kentucky, 6142",
    "registered": "2016-02-16T07:51:36 -00:00",
    "latitude": -69.55902,
    "longitude": 49.509631
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d0210036f470ba9906f",
    "balance": "2,268.91",
    "age": 46,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Reba",
      "last": "Osborne"
    },
    "company": "Ovation",
    "email": "rebaosborne@ovation.com",
    "phone": "+1 (905) 502-3225",
    "address": "586 Beaver Street, Edenburg, Wyoming, 8712",
    "registered": "2016-03-02T06:08:48 -00:00",
    "latitude": 57.737613,
    "longitude": -49.301794
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02f2a230afbc80f82e",
    "balance": "3,633.00",
    "age": 54,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Hardy",
      "last": "Cotton"
    },
    "company": "Futurize",
    "email": "hardycotton@futurize.com",
    "phone": "+1 (969) 427-2003",
    "address": "923 Miami Court, Knowlton, Ohio, 4026",
    "registered": "2016-02-22T07:35:28 -00:00",
    "latitude": 84.25911,
    "longitude": 136.825862
  }, {
    "_id": "5ae30d02519a87f76fc8a0e6",
    "balance": "1,902.75",
    "age": 47,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Ashlee",
      "last": "Gregory"
    }
  }
];

const grouped = groupUsersByFirstName(users);

console.log('first names', Object.keys(grouped));
console.log('grouped users', grouped);
```